# Is it possible to recover data from my previous windows installation?

Tags: windows, video, data-recovery

I had windows installed in my laptop earlier and I forgot to take backup of some videos before erasing the disk and installing Ubuntu, is it possible that I can recover that data?

Please help. Those videos were really important to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No
No because it is difficult

Yes because of recuva

Install same windows version or Try to go to the same place from ubuntu
Now go to same place where it was before
Use recuva to recover

Comment: What do you mean by go to same place with Ubuntu?